# The babysitter read we/us a story about mermaids

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the answer we or us?

> The babysitter read we a story about mermaids.

or

> The babysitter read us a story about mermaids.

Comment: 'We' is a *subject* and 'us' is an *object* of a verb. So "He read to us" and "We read to him".

Comment: When you looked up “we” and “us” in the dictionary to try to figure out the difference, what did you find?

Answer (score 3):

Why do think it might be *we*?

This is a *ditransitive* verb, and like most ditransitives it can take two different patterns:

> The babysitter read a story to us

or

> The babysitter read us a story.

Similarly

> I gave a book to John.

or

> I gave John a book.

and

> Sheila baked a cake for her mother.

or

> Sheila baked her mother a cake.

In either case, pronouns in both object positions (direct and indirect) take the "object" form, *me*, *him*, *her*, *us*, *them*.