# "To read": Is it an intransitive verb?

Tags: meaning-in-context

"Harry had difficulty hiding his glee as he handed the note to Ron **to read**."

From Harry Potter

Is "the note" the object of "to read"? I mean, is it a transitive verb? I think something is omitted: "Harry had difficulty hiding his glee as he handed the note to Ron **for him** to read."

Comment: Although it would be "syntactically valid", we would never repeat the *actual* noun *(**the note**)*. But it could be repeated using a pronoun: *...he handed the note to Ron to read **it***.

Comment: Related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/272027/9161

Comment: Yes:: "the note" is object of "read". The infinitival clause "to read" is functioning as a purpose adjunct in that it has a purposive interpretation: "Harry handed the note to Ron in order that he (Ron) could read it.

Comment: @I'mABot You should not make substantial changes to a question after it has been answered and comments posted.

Comment: Yes: "read" is transitive in your example. There's nothing missing in your first example. "For him to read" simply adds a subject to the to infinitival clause. Both constructions mean the same in that they are both purpose adjuncts.

Comment: @BillJ Thank you, you don't need further explanation. I've already understood it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no explicit object.  The *understood* object of "read" is indeed the note that Harry holds, and the understood subject is "Ron".

It is normal and correct to omit the object in this case, where the object can be easily understood from the context. It it more common with infinitives, but is even possible with finite verbs.

Comment: Can I say “Harry had difficulty hiding his glee as he handed the note to Ron to read it” as Fumble said?

Comment: That is less good,  it seems to introduce an alternate understanding of "Harry gave the note to Ron in order that Harry would  read it"  The sentence is much better without "it".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, *the note* is the direct object of *to read*.

Answer (score 0):

> [1] *Harry had difficulty hiding his glee as he handed the note to Ron* **[** (*for*
> *him) to read* __ **]**.

No, there's nothing missing in [1]. Adding "for him" simply adds a subject to the infinitival clause (bracketed).

Yes: "read" is transitive here. The missing object of "read" is marked by the gap notation '__', which is understood as "the note".

Semantically, the bracketed infinitival clause is a purpose adjunct since it has a purposive interpretation, as seen in [2]:

> *Harry handed the note to Ron in order that he (Ron) could read it*.

Answer (score 0):

> "To read": Is it an intransitive verb?

No. "To read" is an **ambitransitive** verb. These are quite common in English.

**Ambitransitive** verbs are verbs that can be used with or without an object, but, if there is no object, an object can be implied.

Compare

He sat in the chair and read **a book**. Transitive.

He sat in the chair and read. Intransitive.

Both are correct.

If you read, you must read *something*, so you can always add an object and make the verb transitive. However, it is not always necessary to have an object.

Also

He ate [the food/potato/meal, etc.] If you eat, you must eat *something*.

He drove [the car/bus/train, etc] to London If you drive, you must drive *something*.

Without the words in brackets, the verbs are intransitive, with them, they are transitive.